# Persian routing in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I want to have Persian routing like:

"http://mywebsite.com/سلام"

"http://mywebsite.com/شروع/پایان"

"http://mywebsite.com/[slug]/پایان"

What should I do?

Nextjs routing is based on file path, so renaming file names to Persian is not the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with rewrites in the next.config.js file.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Here is an example:

```
module.exports = {
async rewrites() {
    return {
        beforefiles: [{
                source: '/:slug/پایان',
                destination: '/:slug/somewhere',
            },
            {
                source: '/:slug/%d9%be%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%a7%d9%86',
                destination: '/:slug/somewhere'
            }
        ],
    }
  }
}
```

You need to have two rewrites for each route, one normal and one url encoded.